# How to debug in Chrome for newly open window

Tags: google-chrome, debugging

I have a `<a target="_blank" href="newwindow.html">`

I wonder: how can I debug the script of newwindow after I click that link?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to debug script code that runs when the window loads, add a `debugger;` statement to the script - that will drop you into the debugger when that line of script is reached.

Comment: Thanks, but this not work on my side. In my newwindow page, I set the code like: console.log("hello"); debugger; alert("after debugger"); but when I click the link<a target="_blank" href="newwindow.html">, the popup window script can not stop at debugger